# Convert a polynomial w(z) to w((1-z)/(1+z))

Tags: python, symbolic-math

I am writing a code which takes a "code" (Coding Theory) as an input and I have calculated the weight enumerator of it. I want to find the weight enumerator of dual code using [MacWilliams Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerator_polynomial#MacWilliams_identity).

I have `W(z)`, the weight enumerator of the code, and I want to convert it to `W((1-z)/(1+z))` using python.

Comment: What is your question? Do you not know how to calculate it? Not know how to implement that calculation? Both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to be working with polynomials in an extended fashion, you should be working with a proper computer algebra system (CAS). [`sympy`](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) is great for manipulations like these. For example:

```
from sympy import poly
from sympy.abc import x,z

W1 = poly(x**2 + 3*x)

# Evaluate the polynomial at x=(1-z)/(1+z)
W2 = W1((1-z)/(1+z))

print W1
print W2

>>> Poly(x**2 + 3*x, x, domain='ZZ')
>>> (-2*z**2 - 2*z + 4)/(z**2 + 2*z + 1)
```

You can simplify any answer with `sympy.simplify` and `.expand` for example:

```
import sympy

expr = (4*x**2 - 4*x + 4)*(x**3 + 3*x**2 + 3*x + 1)/(4*(x**2 + 2*x + 1))
print sympy.simplify(sympy.expand(expr))
>>> x**3 + 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have computed the polynomial as you told. Now, I have another problem. I have written down my problem here : 


[Code](http://goo.gl/JKbkru)

Comment: @MananDhawan I've added an example on how to simplify, hope it helps.